# Using Google Drive in terminal without autosaving

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, google-drive-api

I wanted to attach my Google Drive to my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04) so that I could access it via my terminal.

I learned that I could install google-drive-ocamlfuse to do this.

The only problem is that if I am editing a file in my terminal, that is in the Google Drive, I am constantly getting told that changes have been saved and do I want to overwrite.

I think this is just because Google Drive autosaves all the time.

Is there any way to disable the autosave in Google Drive? I don't really want to do that, but I also don't want to have to confirm that I want to continue all the time when editing a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can turn Drive API's autosave future. There's no mention of that in the docs. It's also mentioned in this [google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/Bf0gVWCD_j4/NCDZiv6bkWkJ).